# How do I use transform-result in rest API using MarkLogic search?

Tags: marklogic

How do I transform the results in search using the rest API; specifically the snippet part?

I'm currently looking at this
[document](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_58295) but I can't understand where to put it since there are so many ways to add such a thing.

I'm trying to get the whole document put into the snippet part.

```
<transform-results apply="snippet">
    <per-match-tokens>30</per-match-tokens>
    <max-matches>4</max-matches>
    <max-snippet-chars>200</max-snippet-chars>
    <preferred-matches/>
</transform-results>
```

It would be helpful if there were some kind of examples.

Comment: One footnote to Geert's good answer -- as an alternative, you can get a set of documents of any format with a bulk search.  See:  http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/bulk#id_65903

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here a pretty common example of default snippeting, as well as a few results states for different snippeting:

```
<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">

  <!-- The default snippeting behavior, average size snippets, if no results state was specified -->
  <transform-results apply="snippet">
    <preferred-elements>
      <element ns="" name="body"/>
    </preferred-elements>
    <max-matches>2</max-matches>
    <max-snippet-chars>200</max-snippet-chars>
    <per-match-tokens>20</per-match-tokens>
  </transform-results>

  <!-- Pass in operator-state or use results: to select one of these states -->
  <operator name="results">

    <!-- results:compact, returns smallest snippets -->
    <state name="compact">
      <transform-results apply="snippet">
        <preferred-elements>
          <element ns="" name="body"/>
        </preferred-elements>
        <max-matches>1</max-matches>
        <max-snippet-chars>100</max-snippet-chars>
        <per-match-tokens>10</per-match-tokens>
      </transform-results>
    </state>

    <!-- results:detailed, returns largest snippets -->
    <state name="detailed">
      <transform-results apply="snippet">
        <preferred-elements>
          <element ns="" name="body"/>
        </preferred-elements>
        <max-matches>3</max-matches>
        <max-snippet-chars>300</max-snippet-chars>
        <per-match-tokens>30</per-match-tokens>
      </transform-results>
    </state>

    <!-- results:raw, returns full documents -->
    <state name="raw">
      <transform-results apply="raw"/>
    </state>
  </operator>

</options>
```

You can easily blend in operator state selection in your search string, just add something like `results:detailed`. You can also use `operator-state` in structured queries.

HTH!

Comment: for me using `<transform-results name="metadata-snippet">` with `<preferred-elements>` worked to get the entire content of the body but other result types didn't work.

Comment: Please open a new SO question if you'd like to raise attention to a new issue.

Comment: Its the same issue i am talking about.